# Create lag onto next group in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lag

Hi I would like to create a lag by one whole group on a dataframe in R.
So lets say the value for the group A is 11 I would like to make a lag where all values of group B are 11 and so on. Below is an example of what I would like to do.

```
Letter = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D')
Value = c(11, 11, 11, 4, 8, 8, 10)
data.frame(Letter, Value)

  Letter Value
1      A    11
2      A    11
3      A    11
4      B     4
5      C     8
6      C     8
7      D    10
```

And then have it become after the lag:

```
Lag = c(NA, NA, NA, 11, 4, 4, 8)
data.frame(Letter, Value, Lag)

 Letter Value Lag
1      A    11  NA
2      A    11  NA
3      A    11  NA
4      B     4  11
5      C     8   4
6      C     8   4
7      D    10   8
```

(One thing to note is all values of the group will be the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the unique rows of the data, lag Value and then left join the original data frame with that.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  left_join(mutate(distinct(.), Lag = lag(Value), Value = NULL), by = "Letter")
```

giving:

```
  Letter Value Lag
1      A    11  NA
2      A    11  NA
3      A    11  NA
4      B     4  11
5      C     8   4
6      C     8   4
7      D    10   8
```

Comment: In case you want to update your approach with a larger lag as requested by the TO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72688570/create-lag-onto-next-group-in-r/72688714?noredirect=1#comment128396590_72688714

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (see below)

- We first group by LETTER and assign an id to each group member.
- Next we ungroup and assign the lag value if something is the first group member.
- And the final step is to fill the missings.

NOTE: all of this assumes your data set is sorted to your needs so that it would be correct to take the lag value from the last group.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(Letter, Value) |> 
  group_by(Letter) |> 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(Lag = ifelse(id == 1, lag(Value), NA)) |> 
  fill(Lag) |>
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 7 × 3
  Letter Value   Lag
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         11    NA
2 A         11    NA
3 A         11    NA
4 B          4    11
5 C          8     4
6 C          8     4
7 D         10     8
```

Comment: This is a great solution thank you! Is it possible to adapt this to delay it lets say by 2 or 3 groups instead of 1

Comment: This is done much easier with @G.Grothendieck's approach by simply adding the `n` argument to the lag function: `data.frame(Letter, Value) %>%
    left_join(mutate(distinct(.), Lag = lag(Value, n = 2), Value = NULL), by = "Letter")`